# AngularJS JSTL insert

Tags: sql, jsp, jstl, crud

I use jstl sql for prototyping and would like to use it with angularjs. The code below results in empty fields in my database. How do I catch the parameter in the jstl sql code?

**form.html:**

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="crudCtrl">        
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**ctrl.js:**

```
function crudCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.name = name;
    $scope.url = 'create.jsp';
    $scope.submit = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $scope.url,
            data: $scope.name,
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.result = data;
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Fail";
            $scope.status = status;
        });
    }
}
```

**create.jsp:**

```
<sql:update dataSource="jdbc/postgres">
    INSERT INTO mySchema.test
    (
        name
    )
    VALUES(?)
    <sql:param value="${name}"/>
</sql:update>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<sql:param value="${param.name}"/>
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71043 for a list of JSP EL implicit objects.